# The Cartesian product of two disjoint normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite  group with $K \lhd G$ and $N \lhd G , \ K \cap N = \{ e \} $

if $Ord(G) = Ord(K) \cdot Ord(N) \Longrightarrow  G \cong K\times N  $

Could you please check my proof:

Since $K$ and $N$ are subgroups then so is $K\times N  $
and since $\ K \cap N = \langle e \rangle$ then $| K \times N | = |K| |N|$

it follows then that $G \cong K \times N $

It appears to me that this proof is weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not bad, you are heading in the right direction. The notation $\times$ is mostly used for an *external* direct product. Better show first that $G=KN$. To this end, you use the formula $|KN|=(|K| \cdot |N|)/|K \cap N|$. Because $K \cap N = 1$ (in group theory one usually writes $1$ in stead of $\{e\}$ or $\{1\}$) and $|G|=|K||N|$, you can conclude that $G=KN$. And then define a map $\phi: G \rightarrow K \times N$ by $\phi(g)=(k,n)$, if $g=kn$ for some $k \in K$ and $n \in N$. I leave it to you to show that
(1) The choice of $k$ and $n$ is unique, whence $\phi$ is well-defined;
(2) $\phi$ is a homomorphism; 
(3) $\phi$ is injective, whence surjective since $G$ and $K \times N$ have the same order.
And then you can conclude $G \cong K \times N$.

Comment: whence thank you very much. $:)$